# Network is unreachable / Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet, ping

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (x64) via VMWare (my main OS is Windows 10) for the last month.
Recently when I try to ping ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com) for example) I get

`ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

I followed some answers on different posts about this and yesterday, when I added the next line:
`nameserver 8.8.8.8` to my `/etc/resolv.conf` it fixed it for me.

Today, after I rebooted the machine this problem happening again, but this time adding the `nameserver 8.8.8.8` didn't work, and when I try to `ping 8.8.8.8` I get:

`ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

I tried doing the proposed answers there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393818/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-continuously, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090706/connect-network-is-unreachable
but that didn't help neither.

Additional info: on my main OS (Windows 10 x64) everything is working completely fine.

Now, when I look through my host it seems that the vmnet1 & 8 have no dhcp enabled, but I can't figure out how to enable it.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460886/165358) (ensure you can undo it).